# Multiple Authhentication Policies in Pyramid

Tags: python, api, rest, authentication, pyramid

I have received the task of adding HTTP authentication([BasicAuthAuthenticationPolicy](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth/basic.html)) to a Pyramid application that already have a [AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy](http://pyramid-stevepiercy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/pyramid/authentication.html#AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy) implemented...

Basically I need to create a RESTful API to authenticate users(Could I use [BasicAuthAuthenticationPolicy](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth/basic.html) for that?).

Is there a way to check whether a user is using the web interface, or using the api - to check which Authentication Policy to use?

I have not come across documentation that covers two different Authentication Policies in a single Pyramid application(if its even possible).

PS:
I have come across a blog series that started showing how to create a RESTful API with the pyramid framework... The Blogger reported that there was going to be 6 articles in the sersies, however I only managed to find two of those articles: [Building a RESTful API with Pyramid - Setup](https://zaiste.net/building_a_restful_api_with_pyramid_setup/) and [Building a RESTful API with Pyramid - Resource and Traversal](https://zaiste.net/building_a_restful_api_with_pyramid_resource_and_traversal/). I am/was looking forward to his last article: Building a RESTful API with Pyramid - Authentication and ACL, but it doesn't seem like he is going to finish the series.

To recap my questions:

1. Could I use [BasicAuthAuthenticationPolicy](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth/basic.html) for building a RESTful api to authenticate users?
2. Is there a way to check whether a user is using the web interface, or using the API - to check which Authentication Policy to use?

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did was I merged Pyramids `BasicAuthAuthenticationPolicy` and `CallbackAuthenticationPolicy` and I ended up with [this](http://pastebin.com/HMRCAdPd).

I have modified the `callback` method to use a `redis` session

To use this class(HTTPAthentication) you can do something like(this is an example how I implemented it for my usecase):

```
def _get_userid(details, request):
    userre = re.compile("""^([a-zA-Z1-9\.]+):([a-zA-Z1-9\.:-]+)$""", re.I)
    userpass = base64.b64decode(details[1])
    res = userre.search(userpass)
    if res:
        return res.group()[0]

def authcheck(username, password, request):
    user = Users.by_username(username, enabled=True)
    host = request.registry.settings.get("authentication.host", "127.0.0.1")
    maxattempts = request.registry.settings.get("authentication.maxattempts",5)
    base = _get_userid(request.authorization, request)
    if request.redis.exists("pimssess:%s" % base64.b64encode(request.remote_addr+":"+base)):
        store = pickle.loads(request.redis.get("pimssess:%s" % base64.b64encode(request.remote_addr+":"+base)))
        if store.get("auth.attempts").get(request.remote_addr):
            if store["auth.attempts"][request.remote_addr] >= maxattempts:
                raise HTTPMethodNotAllowed(body="You have been locked out for 5 minutes")

    if user and user.agent and not user.is_http_auth:
        raise HTTPMethodNotAllowed(body="You are not permitted http access")
    if user and user.agent and user.host != host:
        raise HTTPMethodNotAllowed(body="Your host is not permitted http access")
    if user and user.agent and not user.validate_password(password):
        time.sleep(1.5)
        raise HTTPForbidden(body="Failed login, Incorrect password")
    return getGroups(username)
```

The getGroups function retruns a list of `groups` that is attached to the user , i.e. `['admin', 'reporting']`

I followed this example: [BasicAuthAuthenticationPolicy](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth/basic.html)(scroll to bottom)

And for the web interface login(CallbackAuthentication), you create a login interface, and create the view to accommodate the template(checking for password and username match, etc.)

Oh I almost forgot... In your project `__init__.py`, when you call the `AuthPolicy`, in the `def main(...)`. I did:

```
authentication = AuthPolicy(secret='@#^&*$!DSYUIDSA8321789DS',
                        hashalg='sha512', check=authcheck, debug=True)
authorization = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()

config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=RootFactory,
                  authentication_policy=authentication,
                  authorization_policy=authorization)
```

I do hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Pyramid does not make it easy to use different policies for different parts of the app (maybe something to work around with custom decorators) but for multiple policies check out [pyramid_authstack](https://github.com/wichert/pyramid_authstack). I'm using it with Session and BasicAuth policies for the same purpose as you are.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not straightforward having one pyramid app with two auth policies you can have TWO separate Pyramid apps with a different policy each assembled into a single WSGI stack. Each app can import the same Python code, so, essentially, it'll be two startup files using the same views and everything.

If your apps have different URLs you can use [paste.urlmap](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/urlmap.html) for this, and if your requirements are more complex you can even write your own router (say, requests with a certain HTTP header are routed to one app and without it to another)